# Http method set in the API call changes when seen in the chrome Dev tools

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to call an API using

```
createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers) {
     headers.append('Authorization',
   'Bearer ' +   JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('access_token')).access_token));}

getAllData() {
 let headers = new Headers();
 this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
 return this.http.get('url'
  { headers: headers }
 ).map((response) => {
 response.json();
});
```

here i am sending the request using the GET Http Method, but in the chrome dev tools i see the Request method is set to Options, which is not allowed in the API.

but if i comment out the headers in the this.http.get then, in the chrome dev tools i see the correct http request method.
Any suggestions why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely making a cross-domain request here.

When making a cross-domain (CORS) request, Chrome will send a pre-flight (OPTIONS) requests to your API first to discover if the AngularJS request should be trusted by your API.

Therefore if you're going to host your AngularJS client and API on different domains, you'll have to allow OPTIONS requests and ensure CORS is properly configured on your API.

Comment: thanks Ben... sorry for the delayed response from my end.

Comment: No worries, was this the cause of your issue?

Comment: yeah... i forgot that i asked on stackoverflow. just out of hunch i looked at the backend code and it turns out the issue was as you said related to CORS. Initially i didnt have access to the backend code, i had to wait for the approval.
thanks Anyways..